# How do I convert a string into a sequence of characters in Nim?

Tags: nim-lang

I want to do different operations with the characters in a string e.g. map or reverse. As a first step I want to convert the string into a sequence.

Given a string like "ab". 
How do I get a sequence like `@['a','b']`?

`"ab".split("")` returns the whole string.

I have seen an example with `"ab".items` before, but that doesn't seem to work (is that deprecated?)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`items` is an iterator, not a function, so you can only call it in a few specific contexts (like `for` loop). However, you can easily construct a sequence from an iterator using `toSeq` from `sequtils` module ([docs](https://nim-lang.org/docs/sequtils.html#toSeq.t,untyped)). E.g.:

```
import sequtils
echo toSeq("ab".items)
```

Answer (score 5):

Since `string` is implemented like `seq[char]` a simple cast suffices, i.e.

```
echo cast[seq[char]]("casting is formidable")
```

this is obviously the most efficient approach, since it's just a cast, though perhaps some of the other approaches outlined in the answers here get optimized by the compiler to this.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
import future

let
  text = "nim lang"
  parts = lc[c | (c <- text), char]
```

Parts is `@['n', 'i', 'm', ' ', 'l', 'a', 'n', 'g']`.

Comment: List comprehensions are deprecated since version 0.19.9.

Comment: @danlei: So, what do you suggest instead?

Comment: Well, you could use a library like [comprehension](https://github.com/alehander42/comprehension) or maybe [for loop macros](https://nim-lang.org/docs/manual.html#macros-for-loop-macro), but I haven't used them myself, so you'd have to check them out yourself.

Answer (score 4):

Here's another variant using `map` from `sequtils` and `=>` from `future` (renamed to `sugar` on Nim devel):

```
import sequtils, sugar
echo "nim lang".map(c => c)
```

Outputs `@['n', 'i', 'm', ' ', 'l', 'a', 'n', 'g']`.

Comment: If you don't want to rely on future or sugar you can use mapIt("abc", it)

Answer (score 2):

A string already is a sequence of chars:

```
assert "ab" == @['a', 'b']

import sequtils
assert "ab".mapIt(it.ord) == @[97, 98]
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do this:

```
import sequtils
echo "ab".toSeq()
```

Answer (score 0):

`@` converts both arrays *and* strings to sequences:

```
echo @"abc"
```

Output: @['a', 'b', 'c']